# Error when creating a generated column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, string-concatenation

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
   id  serial primary key,
   accNum  text UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
 concat(right(cast(extract year from current_date) as text), 2), cast(id as text)) STORED
);
```

**Error:** generation expression is not immutable

The goal is to populate the accNum field with YYid where YY is the last two letters of the year when the person was added.

I also tried the '||' operator but it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't expect the column to be updated, when the row is changed, you can define your own function that generates the number:

```
create function generate_acc_num(id int)
returns text
as
$$
  select to_char(current_date, 'YY')||id::text;
$$
language sql
immutable; --<< this is lying to Postgres!
```

Note that you should **never** use this function for any other purpose. *Especially* not as an index expression.

Then you can use that in a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
  id  integer generated always as identity primary key,
  acc_num  text UNIQUE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (generate_acc_num(id)) STORED
);
```

Comment: That is ugly. A trigger would be much better.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Yh but with generated columns, inserting a value for the column easily raises an error.

Comment: @BihTracy I don't understand. But I guess it doesn't matter, if it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

As @ScottNeville correctly mentioned:

`CURRENT_DATE` is not immutable. So it cannot be used int a `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` expression.

However, you can achieve this using a trigger nevertheless:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=950fc324fa8d2a857198bbb9a8c85f40)

```
CREATE FUNCTION accnum_trigger_function() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER 
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.accNum := right(extract(year from current_date)::text, 2) || NEW.id::text;
   
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_accnum
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON person
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE accnum_trigger_function();
```

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned correctly in the comments: You can simplify the expression to:

```
NEW.accNum := to_char(current_date, 'YY') || NEW.id;
```

Comment: Or a bit simpler: `to_char(current_date, 'YY')`

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure how to solve this problem (maybe a trigger), but current_date is a stable function not an immutable one.  For the generated IDs I believe all function calls must be immutable.  You can read more here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html

I dont think any function that gets the date can be immutable as Postgres defines this as "An IMMUTABLE function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments forever."  This will not be true for anything that returns the current date.

I think your best bet would be to do this with a trigger so on insert it sets the value.